# Clearing intervals on mouse movement with object functions

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time working this one out. I want to run a screensaver type of interaction where if the user is idle (no mouse movement) for longer than X then it runs and then when the user is active it clears and stops.

My issue is even though the screensaver initially seems to work (idle after 5 seconds) after the first idle and thus mouse movement to clear/stop; it instantly comes back on (instead of waiting 5 seconds) and then the `screensaverBuildUp` interval seems to speed up (rather than run every 1 second).

Any thoughts where I'm going wrong?

```
const dev = {};

dev.interactions = {

    init: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {

        let mouseTimeout, screensaverBuildUp;
        dev.ui.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
            dev.interactions.screensaverClear(screensaverBuildUp);
            clearTimeout(mouseTimeout);
            mouseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                dev.interactions.screensaver(screensaverBuildUp);
            }, 5000);
        });

    },

    screensaverRun: function(screensaverRun) {

        screensaverBuildUp = setInterval(function() {

            let $screensaver = document.querySelector('div.screensaver'),
                $graphics = $screensaver.querySelectorAll('img'),
                $randomGraphic = $graphics[Math.floor(Math.random() * $graphics.length)],
                $clonedRandomGraphic = $randomGraphic.cloneNode(true);

            $screensaver.style.display = 'block';

            // Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            $clonedRandomGraphic.removeAttribute('style');
            $clonedRandomGraphic.removeAttribute('class');
            $clonedRandomGraphic.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (95 - (-5) + 1) + (-5)) + '%';
            $clonedRandomGraphic.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (95 - (-5) + 1) + (-5)) + '%';
            $clonedRandomGraphic.style.transform = 'rotate(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - (-360) + 1) + (-360)) + 'deg)';
            $screensaver.appendChild($clonedRandomGraphic);

            if ($graphics.length === 50) {
                clearInterval(screensaverBuildUp);
            }

        }, 1000);

    },

    screensaverClear: function(screensaverRun) {

        clearInterval(screensaverBuildUp);

        let $screensaver = document.querySelector('div.screensaver'),
            $graphics = $screensaver.querySelectorAll('img:not(.base)');

        $screensaver.style.display = 'none';

        $graphics.forEach(function($graphic) {
            $graphic.remove();
        });

    }

};
dev.interactions.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the scope of your variables. You need to define them at a higher level so each function has access to it

When you declared your internal in `screensaverRun` with `screensaverBuildUp = setInterval(function(`. This created the internal timer on a global variable `screensaverBuildUp` and when you are clearing the timer with `dev.interactions.screensaverClear(screensaverBuildUp);` in your bind function, that only clears the variable `screensaverBuildUp` declared with `let mouseTimeout, screensaverBuildUp;` in the bind function only. So your global `screensaverBuildUp` never gets cleared which is why you see it run.

I have simplified the code to demonstrate a working solution. Hover over the area to run and you will see the console log.

`screensaverBuildUp: null,` is declared at a higher level so it can be accessed by all your functions but not a global variable

```js
const dev = {};

dev.interactions = {

  mouseTimeout: null,
  screensaverBuildUp: null,

  init: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {

    document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
      dev.interactions.screensaverClear(dev.interactions.screensaverBuildUp);

      clearTimeout( dev.interactions.mouseTimeout );
      dev.interactions.mouseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        dev.interactions.screensaverRun();
        console.log( "run screensaver timer" );
      }, 3000);
    });

  },

  screensaverRun: function() {

    dev.interactions.screensaverBuildUp = setInterval(function() {

      console.log("interval fired")

    }, 1000);

  },

  screensaverClear: function(screensaverRun) {

    clearInterval( dev.interactions.screensaverBuildUp );
    console.log("screensaver cleared");

  }

};
dev.interactions.init();
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px
}
```